# Creating component in Swing where text field takes only date type value

Tags: java, swing

I want to create component in Swing where text field takes only date type value.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `JFormattedTextField`, setting your format for the date.  Works without using anything outside of the JRE, but might not be the most usable option.

Otherwise do what eugener said and use SwingX's `JXDatePicker` or JIDE's `DateComboBox`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SwingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net/) library. It is free and has a very good component called JXDatePicker

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for you:

- create an editable text field that parses for a date format on insert, using a `DocumentListener` or a custom `Document`
- create an editable text field that gets parsed for a valid date format on loss of focus or validated on an `ActionEvent` triggered by a submit button
- create a non-editable text field with spinner buttons that increment/decrement the date string that you define
- use a 3rd party library as @eugener suggests

If you have a specific problem creating your component, please post the code you have been working on and we will be happy to help further.